# Read MYD, MYI, FRM files

Tags: mysql

I've read several posts on this forum and others and still can't read some MYD/MYI/FRM files which contain data that I want to import into SQL Server.

- I stopped the MySQL service at the client location and copied all the files (the same way that we would do with SQL Server).
- I have installed the most recent MySQL ODBC connector, MySQL engine and MySQL Workbench on my Windows 10 PC.  The engine is running and the ODBC connector is configured with a username and password.  Using the workbench, I have been able to successfully log in.
- I created a MyTest database which created a C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\mytest folder.
- I stopped the MySQL service and copied MyData.MYD, MyData.MYI and MyData.FRM to the mytest folder.
- I restarted the MySQL service.

But if I run a "Select * from mytest.MyData" query in the workbench or using the MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client, it keeps indicating that the table mytest.MyData doesn't exist.  Now, I read that it might be appropriate to run a CHOWN command but I don't know what if syntax would be different for a Windows system and whether this command would be executed directly from a Command prompt.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of MySQL let you get away with that for MyISAM tables, but MySQL 8.0 introduced a whole new implementation of "data dictionary" which is a meta-database maintained internally, and it has a bias for InnoDB over MyISAM. So I would believe that moving files around ad hoc no longer works as it once did. To move tables from one instance to another, you should really do the export and import steps properly.

For InnoDB, you may use [transportable tablespaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-table-import.html). At least you don't have to do a full data import that way, but it takes a few more steps than just file copy.

P.S.: I haven't used MyISAM in many years anyway. I prefer my database to support ACID properties, and MyISAM does not support any of the ACID properties.

Comment: The link that you provided only refers to InnoDB files.  So are we saying that MySQL 8.0 cannot "import" MyISAM files?  If such is the case, then I should download the engine and tools for a prior version of MySQL?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm saying the time to use MyISAM tables passed at least ten years ago. I would recommend you use InnoDB and stop using MyISAM. InnoDB has better performance, better reliability, and better features. Future development in MySQL will focus on InnoDB, and MyISAM is not advancing. Don't get stuck using old versions of MySQL. That's my opinion.

Comment: Bill, as I indicated in my original post, my objective is to take a client's MySQL files and convert them over to a modern SQL Server.  So although I'm sure that you are 100% correct in saying that MyISAM is deprecated tech, I still need to determine how to read the data in order to migrate it to something more modern.  So then would I be right in thinking that the ONLY way would be to download a prior version of MySQL engine and tools?

Comment: You can either use an old version of MySQL, or else use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) to export the data to a storage engine-independent format (SQL file), and then import it to whatever instance you want.